# DataBinding in ListView with Namespaces

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding

According to the [Xamarin tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding) I can bind properties from XAML to, for instance, observable collection properties.

The only difference is, I **am** using a namespace for my collection items class.

After implementing my simple version of the tutorial, however, I end up with an empty list. I am currently using a simple `ListView` to learn more about bindings.

Now, my model is simple:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Testapp.Models // This originally was NOT inside a namespace "Model"
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Title;

        public string Description;

        public Image Icon;
    }
}
```

And my C# code implements a property `Items` that returns an `ObservableCollection<Item>`, just like the tutorial, or at least that is what I see:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Testapp.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Testapp.Pages
{
    public partial class ItemizedPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get { return ItemsCollection; } }

        public ItemizedPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ItemizedView.ItemsSource = Items;

            ItemsCollection.Add(new Item { Title = "Item One", Description = "Something" });
            ItemsCollection.Add(new Item { Title = "Thing Two", Description = "Someone" });
            ItemsCollection.Add(new Item { Title = "Whatever Three", Description = "Somewhere" });
        }
    }
}
```

The relative XAML code is, again, from the tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Testapp.Pages.ItemizedPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemizedView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

As far as I see, this should be working fine, but it isn't. The `ListView` is empty.

What am I missing here? Is it a problem that the model `Item` is inside a folder and XAML can't access it?

For reference, this is Visual Studio for Mac 8.9.7 build 8, with Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the variables defined in `Item` to [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) .

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Image Icon { get; set; }
    }
```